# CS50 pset6 // cash.py // Not Showing The Proper amount of coins needed

Tags: python, computer-science, cs50

I have been trying to fix this issue but in the task, for pset6 it says that you need to test the code you wrote with some values it works for some of them but for the rest, it doesn't work I am not sure why.

so the image below is the values that I need to try the code I wrote works for the first 3 inputs but after 0.15 the values like 1.60, 23, and 4.2 does not work I am not sure why

[image]

```
from cs50 import get_float

coin_count =0
change = get_float("Enter Change Amount: ")
total_amount = round(change * 100);
coin_amounts = [25,10,5,1]

while change<=0:
    change = get_float("Enter Change Amount: ")

while total_amount > 0:
    for i in coin_amounts:
        if total_amount >=i:
            total_amount  -= i
            coin_count+=1

print(str(coin_count) + " coins");
```

Comment: this is not C code, looks like python

Comment: yes sorry i got it mixed up because I was doing the same task in C aswell thanks for reminding me

Comment: What does it output for 1.6 etc ? Also you calculate `total_amount` before checking `change > 0` - not your problem, but not right either :-)

Comment: the output for 1.6 is 16 coins but it should be 7
the output for 23 is 228 but it should be 92
and the output for 4.2 is 41 but it should be18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work through the logic.

Lets say you start with 1.6 (160).

160 > 25 so remove 25

135 > 10 so remove 10

125 > 5 so remove 5

120 > 1 so remove 1

119 > 25 so remove 25

See the problem ?

When you get into bigger numbers having removed 10 then 5 then 25 then 10 again means you go off the rails - those [10 10 5] could be a single 25.
You need to remove as many 25s as you can before removing all the 10s that you can then all the 5s and what is left has to be 1s.

Comment: ah i see so does that mean the method that I am using with the for loop going through the list of coin amounts wont work for this?

Comment: It will work but not in it's current form. I'm not going to just give you a home work dump but for each coin you need to keep going until you can't take off any more then move to the next denomination.

Comment: alright thank you for your help I will try this out appreciate it